# entity framework 4.1 invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have two table News and NewsComments. I followed the rules of naming

structure NewsComments

```
public class NewsComment : BaseComment
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

    public virtual News News { get; set; }      
}
```

But query return exception Invalid column name "News_Id". I know what this exception created when in table not related column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewsComments](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[NewsId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Text] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CommentDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Ip] [varchar](40) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_NewsComments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**BaseComment**

```
public abstract class BaseComment : BasePersistentEntity, IComment
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual BaseUser User { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "CommentText")]
    public string Text { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "CommentDate")]
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }


    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

**News**

```
public class News : BaseContent
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(NewsResurce), Name = "NewsImage")]
    public string NewsImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsCommentView> CommentViews { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseContent**

```
public abstract class BaseContent : BasePersistentEntity
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Keywords")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "TitleTranslit")]
    public string TitleTranslit { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsTextEmpty")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Contents")]
    public string Contents { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "DatePublish")]
    public DateTime DatePublish { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "AuthorPublish")]
    public string AuthorPublish { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "AuthorUrl")]
    public string AuthorUrl { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Views")]      
    public int Views { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Comments")]
    public int Comments { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "IsComment")]
    public bool IsComment { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "SumVote")]
    public int SumVote { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "VoteCount")]
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FrameworkResurce), Name = "Rating")]
    public double Rating
    {
        get
        {
            if (VoteCount > 0)
            {
                return Math.Round((float)SumVote/VoteCount, 2);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
private IEnumerable<NewsComment> GetComments()
    {
        var news = NewsCommentRepository.AllIncluding(c=>c.User,c=>c.News);
        return news;
    }

private DataRepository<NewsComment> NewsCommentRepository
        {
            get { return DataRepository<NewsComment>.Repository; }
        }
```

**DataRepository**

```
public class DataRepository<T> where T : BasePersistentEntity
{
    public static DataRepository<T>  Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return new DataRepository<T>();
        }
    }

    private readonly SGNContext<T> context = new SGNContext<T>();

    public IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get { return this.context.Table; }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this.context.Table;
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    public T Find(int id)
    {
        return this.context.Table.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(T country)
    {
        if (country.Id == default(int))
        {
            // New entity
            this.context.Table.Add(country);
            Save();
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            this.context.Entry(country).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var country = this.context.Table.Find(id);
        this.context.Table.Remove(country);
        this.Save();
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Where used GetComments**

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult AjaxCommentsBinding()
    {
        return View(new GridModel<NewsComment>
        {
            Data = GetComments()
        });
    }
```

**NewsCommentViews**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[NewsCommentViews]
AS
SELECT     dbo.NewsComments.NewsId, dbo.NewsComments.Text, dbo.NewsComments.UserId, dbo.NewsComments.CommentDate, dbo.NewsComments.Ip, 
                      dbo.Roles.RoleName, dbo.Users.UserName, dbo.Users.DateRegistered, dbo.NewsComments.Id, dbo.Users.Avatar
FROM         dbo.NewsComments INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Users ON dbo.NewsComments.UserId = dbo.Users.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Roles ON dbo.Users.RoleId = dbo.Roles.Id
```

**NewsCommentViews**

```
[Table("NewsCommentViews")]
    public class NewsCommentView : NewsComment
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }

        public string Avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the query which causes the exception? Perhaps also the `News` and `BaseComment` class. Do you have any mapping code in Fluent API?

Comment: Can you also show the query which throws the exception?

Comment: Next two questions: 1) How does `NewsCommentView` look? 2) Can you show exactly the code where you **use** the query `GetComments()`? It's only an `IQueryable/IEnumerable`, so the query is not executed in `GetComments` but somewhere else. Please also point exactly to the line which throws the exception.

Comment: And how is the `NewsCommentView` **class** in your model defined?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is in the relationship between `News` and `NewsCommentView`: One end of the relationship is the `News.CommentViews` collection. But the other end is **not** `NewsCommentView.News` as you perhaps expect. Why? Because the property `News` is not **declared** on the `NewsCommentView` class but on the **base class** `NewsComment`. Now EF doesn't allow that an entity participates in a relationship with a navigation property which is not **declared** on that entity class itself but only in a base class.

So, because you don't have Fluent mapping EF defines all relationships only by conventions. What happens?

- `News` has a navigation property `CommentViews` declared and pointing to the `NewsCommentView` class.
- EF does not find an inverse property of type `News` which is **declared** in the `NewsCommentView` class. (There is one but it's in the base class, which doesn't count.)
- So, EF assumes the other end of the relationship is **not exposed** in the `NewsCommentView` class.
- Not exposed means: EF doesn't have a navigation property nor a foreign key property and will assume that the necessary foreign key columns in the database table/view `NewsCommentViews` will have a standard conventional name.
- This conventional name is `NameOfEntityClass_PKPropertyName` -> `News_Id`

Your real name in the view is `NewsId` though. So, EF queries for a column `News_Id` which doesn't exist, hence the exception.

The exception is probably triggered due to lazy loading when your MVC-View accesses `NewsComment.News.CommentViews`.

You can fix this problem by specifying the FK column name explicitely in Fluent API (as far as I know there no other way without Fluent mapping):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<News>()
            .HasMany(n => n.CommentViews)
            .WithRequired() // <- no param because not exposed end of relation,
                            // nc => nc.News would throw an exception
                            // because nc.News is in the base class
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("NewsId"));
    }
}
```

But **caution**: Be aware that `NewsCommentView.News` is **not** the other end of the relationship belonging to `News.CommentViews`. It means that if you have a `NewsCommentView` in your `News.CommentViews` collection then `NewsCommentView.News` does **not** point back to that `News` object. The other end is invisible and not exposed in the model. The mapping above just fixes the FK column name problem but doesn't change the relationships which conventions would create anyway (except maybe changing the relationship to required instead of optional).

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL does not have an underscore between user and id.

Update EDMX from database (via right click menu) and check the mappings.

Comment: I see that now that you edited your question. Where did you map the property NewsId to the (non-existing) column News_Id? - Search your code. Try deleting the output files if you already corrected that in your code.