# Can't get EF code first one-to-many working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Picking up from post:
[Define one-to-one in EF code first with fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421700/define-one-to-one-in-ef-code-first-with-fluent-api)
where I had trouble getting a one-to-one working, I now have another problem with a one-to-many.

Here are my two classes:

```
[Table("PSCStatuses")]
public class PSCStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int PSCStatusID { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusTextDesc { get; set; }
    public int NumDaysToProjEndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}

public class Case
{
    // Key: Tells EF this is the PK for Case.
    // ForeignKey("Appointee"): tells EF Appointee is the Principle/Parent in the 1:1
    [Required]
    [Key, ForeignKey("Appointee")]  
    public string ProfileID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? PSCStatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual PSCStatus PSCStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Appointee Appointee { get; set; }
}
```

You can see here what I had to do in my previous post to get Case to have one Appointee. (And Appointee to have a Case where Appointee is the Principle/Parent).
I don't recall ever having to jump through hoops with EF before. But I think I am very rusty here.

Now after solving that I have a new problem.
I can't get Case to fill in PSCStatus.
When I inspect Case.PSCStatus at a break point after adding the case with the PSCstatusID set, I should see the PSCStatus object filled in and populated.
But it remains null.
I would think that the definition above would tell EF everything it needs to know but it is not working.

I also tried fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Case>()
                    .HasRequired<PSCStatus>(c => c.PSCStatus)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Cases)
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.PSCStatusID);
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the object before you inspect it at a breakpoint? Are you making sure to eager load the PSCStatus?

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`ICollection` insead of `List`

[Edit]

If this doesn't work try this model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Case>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.PSCStatus)
        .WithMany(s => s.Cases)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.PSCStatusID);
```

Comment: Also for lazy loading to work the type must implement `ICollection` and the access must be `public` or `protected`.

Comment: Thanks - I tried both and still no luck.
I just don't know why EF is not listening to my navigation properties and foreign key attributes.

Comment: Is there a reason for the nullable foreign key in the model? Try remove the ?

Comment: Not marking this comment as answer because It's kind of half way there. But, at the break point if I pull the Case back out of the Case Repo, the PSCStatus property is set.  Had a hunch that, yeah I added it, but the current Case I have hold of hasn't had the PSCStatus set yet. You have to go back out to the context and grab that one.